# Query transaction log in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am wondering if it's possible to query transactions using standard query select.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.transaction_logs 
WHERE table_name = 'product' AND time_stamp > '2016-01-01';
```

the result would be something like

```
===> table_name | operation | old_val_json   | new_val_json...
      product   |    update | {....desc:...} | {...desc...}|
```

The query does not work because there is no such table as transaction_logs, but does something similar to this exist?

Comment: No, there is nothing like that built-in. You are probably looking for an audit trigger: http://okbob.blogspot.de/2015/01/most-simply-implementation-of-history.html or http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted, but it's simple enough to implement. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can query write-ahead log stream through a logical replication slot.

First, you need to change a couple of parameters and then restart the server for the changes to take place:

```
postgres=# alter system set wal_level = logical;
postgres=# alter system set max_replication_slots = 1;
```

Then (after restart) you need to create a slot:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_create_logical_replication_slot('slot', 'test_decoding');
 slot_name | xlog_position 
-----------+---------------
 slot      | 2E/839F3300
(1 row)
```

Here, `test_decoding` is an output plugin name which is intended to convert log records (which are binary) to some text representation.

Then let's create a table...

```
postgres=# create table product(id serial, val json);
CREATE TABLE
```

Now you can query WAL stream:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_logical_slot_get_changes('slot', NULL, NULL);
  location   |  xid  |     data     
-------------+-------+--------------
 2E/83A0BA48 | 80243 | BEGIN 80243
 2E/83A1D2B8 | 80243 | COMMIT 80243
(2 rows)
```

Unfortunately, now you can't decode DDL, so you get just BEGIN and END. `Xid` field represents transaction number.

But let's insert something...

```
postgres=# insert into product(val) values ('{"desc":"aaa"}');
INSERT 0 1
```

Now query the stream again:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_logical_slot_get_changes('slot', NULL, NULL);
  location   |  xid  |                                  data                                  
-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2E/83A1D3C0 | 80244 | BEGIN 80244
 2E/83A1D3C0 | 80244 | table public.product: INSERT: id[integer]:1 val[json]:'{"desc":"aaa"}'
 2E/83A1D440 | 80244 | COMMIT 80244
(3 rows)
```

Here you can see the table name and inserted values.

The same for an update statement:

```
postgres=# update product set val = '{"desc":"bbb"}';
UPDATE 1
postgres=# SELECT * FROM pg_logical_slot_get_changes('slot', NULL, NULL);
  location   |  xid  |                                  data                                  
-------------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2E/83A1D560 | 80245 | BEGIN 80245
 2E/83A1D560 | 80245 | table public.product: UPDATE: id[integer]:1 val[json]:'{"desc":"bbb"}'
 2E/83A1D5E8 | 80245 | COMMIT 80245
(3 rows)
```

Note that after you "consume" some changes from the stream by using `pg_logical_slot_get_changes` function, you cannot query the same changes again.

Drop the slot if you need it no more:

```
postgres=# SELECT pg_drop_replication_slot('slot');
 pg_drop_replication_slot 
--------------------------

(1 row)
```

You can read more about logical decoding [in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/logicaldecoding.html).